# Methods to be only available in Unit test

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine, macros

I'm looking for a way to make methods only available in Unit test scripts.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Data MyData { get; }
    internal MyClass()
    {
        // Complex code setting MyData
    }
#if UNITY_MACROS
    public MyClass(MyData data)
    {
         MyData = data;
    }
#endif
}
```

The need is that the public constructor would only be available in the Unit Test scripts and assembly.

I tried to look into Define constraints in the Test assembly but I am probably not using right since I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to use the InternalsVisibleTo attribute ([MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8)). You can add the following line either in your class source file, or in a separate AssemblyInfo.cs which you can create in the same folder as your asmdef file:

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("MyUnitTestAssembly")]
```

In that case you can leave MyClass(MyData data) internal.